# Material UI Select Field multiselect

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I tried several times the example given in the documentation. but it didn't work well for me.
can any one help me....
this is the code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

const names = [
  'Oliver Hansen',
  'Van Henry',
  'April Tucker',
  'Ralph Hubbard',
  'Omar Alexander',
  'Carlos Abbott',
  'Miriam Wagner',
  'Bradley Wilkerson',
  'Virginia Andrews',
  'Kelly Snyder',
];

/**
 * `SelectField` can handle multiple selections. It is enabled with the `multiple` property.
 */
export default class SelectFieldExampleMultiSelect extends Component {
  state = {
    values: [],
  };

  handleChange = (event, index, values) => this.setState({values});

  menuItems(values) {
    return names.map((name) => (
      <MenuItem
        key={name}
        insetChildren={true}
        checked={values && values.indexOf(name) > -1}
        value={name}
        primaryText={name}
      />
    ));
  }

  render() {
    const {values} = this.state;
    return (
      <SelectField
        multiple={true}
        hintText="Select a name"
        value={values}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      >
        {this.menuItems(values)}
      </SelectField>
    );
  }
}
```

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field

the select property works but it doesnt select multiple options. when i check the states.value it only includes a single value not a array of values

Comment: you can take another array and push your values in it.

Comment: Yes, But if it support multi-select it should provide with a array  isn't it...So i went for another plugin ,, It worked for me,,,thank you for the idea.  [https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select-2] 
      [1]:https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select-2

Comment: yes, you can use react multiselect .. it is better option

Comment: yha it worked fine for me,,,,thanx mate.... i suggest for others the multi select...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This example didn't work for me either. To add the multi-select feature you have to manually add the new value to the state, so the handleChange function from the example would look something like this:

```
  handleChange(event, index, values)  { 
    this.setState({ 
     values: [...this.state.values , values]
    });
   }
```

EDIT: I updated my version of material-ui to the latest stable version and their example worked like a charm

Comment: Thank you brother , yha we could do so... But i was looking why there multiselct functionally didn't work... thanx anyway

Comment: So I actually found out why it didn't work @SalindaKrish . You have to update your version of material UI to the latest "stable" version. I updgraded, did an npm install, and then it worked like a charm

Comment: Hmmm ,, may be that may be a reason ,, thanx @Sua Morales

Answer (score 2):

A much better approach is possible. In the lasted version of material UI.

```js
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import MenuText from '@material-ui/core/MenuText';
import {useState} from 'react';

const App = () => {
   const [selected,setSelected] = useState([]); 
   return <Select multiple={true} value={selected} onChange={(event) => setSelected(event.target.value)}>
   <MenuItem>Val - 1</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem>Val - 2</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem>Val - 3</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem>Val - 4</MenuItem>
</Select> 
}
```

**Make sure to set the value of select as an array. Otherwise, It will not work**

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for old material ui version. You can add multiple items and deselect to remove them.

```
handleChange(event, index, values)  { 
   this.setState({ 
     values: [...values]
   });
}
```