# React Select not allowing multiple selections

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a react app that I am currently updating which involves switching to react 16.8 and updating all libraries. I have two drop down selects from material UI, and due to this new version the multi select one no longer allows multiple options to be selected and I can't work out why. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';

const names = [
  'Oliver Hansen',
  'Van Henry',
  'Kelly Snyder',
];



export default function MultipleSelect() {
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = event => {
  console.log(event) //holds the selected option correctly
  setPersonName(event.target.value);
    console.log(personName) 
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl className={classname}>
        <Select
          multiple //used to be isMulti but this also no longer works
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}  
          placeholder = {"choose a name"}
          options={names}
        >
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Material UI Select Field multiselect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44534034/material-ui-select-field-multiselect)

Comment: @PrakashKarena it is the same question but the answer is outdated and doesn't apply to this version of react/material ui so the only answer does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your value always contains a single string value. When you select a second items, it overrides the first value with new one. You need to assign an array of values to value prop with selected values. Push selected item in previously selected values array and update the state and on removal, remove that name from that array.

```js
export default function MultipleSelect() {
  const [selectedNames, setSelectedNames] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = event => {
   console.log(event) //holds the selected option correctly
   // if selection/addition
   setSelectedNames([...selectedNames, event.target.value]);
   
   // On removal,
   
   // setSelectedNames(selectedNames.filter(name => name !== event.target.value));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl className={classname}>
        <Select
          multiple //used to be isMulti but this also no longer works
          value={selectedNames}
          onChange={handleChange}  
          placeholder = {"choose a name"}
          options={names}
        >
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have just realised that on setSelectedNames it should be ...selectedNames, event.target.value instead of ...setSelectedNames. This then works! If you want to update your answer to swap this I will mark it as accepted :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Set true value to `multiple` attribute:

```
   <Select
              multiple="true"
             // ...
            >
              // ...
            </Select>
```

Comment: He is already using `multiple="true"` since default value of any prop is `true` <Component multiple />

Comment: can confirm this makes no difference but thank you for trying

Comment: Yes, this makes no difference but I was using react-validator. It represented different behavior. Because of that, I tried to answer.

Comment: if you're using a standard select field you do need to set it like this (not relevant to this question but this answer helped me)

Answer (score 0):

Your `options` are currently single string. Select expects something like this (notice the value and label properties):

```
[
  {value: 1, label: "Oliver Hansen"},
  {value: 2, label: "Van Henry"},
  {value: 3, label: "Kelly Snyder"}
]
```

If you have that in order your select should be working as expected.